# Qt: Can mouse event handlers block one another?

Tags: qt, event-handling

I have a simple parent widget that reimplements mousePressEvent/mouseReleaseEvent. The parent's child widgets use enterEvent/leaveEvent. When I hover the mouse over the child widgets, leaveEvent/enterEvent executes, but when I click and hold the mouse, mousePressEvent executes, but enterEvent/leaveEvent goes silent (in other words, no click and drag). Any ideas about what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you press and hold down the mouse button on a widget then that widget **grabs** mouse events until you release the button. This is not a special feature of Qt, you can find similar behaviour in every other GUI APIs I know.

Take a look at the relevant part of the Qt documentation:

[QWidget / Events](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QWidget.html#events):

> mousePressEvent() is called when a mouse button is pressed while the
>   mouse cursor is inside the widget, or when the widget has grabbed the
>   mouse using grabMouse(). **Pressing the mouse without releasing it is
>   effectively the same as calling grabMouse().**

[void QWidget::grabMouse ()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#grabMouse):

> Grabs the mouse input. This widget receives all mouse events until
>   releaseMouse() is called; **other widgets get no mouse events at all**.